# Can questions that ask for a comparison be constructive?

Tags: discussion, scope

Every now and then I stumble upon questions that are very useful to me, but are closed nonetheless. Most of the time this concerns questions that ask for a comparison between, for instance, two different technologies. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696884/python-nose-vs-unittest#comment35431990_5696884) whose entire body reads:

> What are the advantages and disadvantages of Python's nose library versus unittest? Are there any reasons to use one versus the other?

To me it feels that such a question is relevant, practical and answerable. Why should they nevertheless be closed?

Comment: The only way you could get a kind of comparison if you have a paractical **specific** problem with one toolset/library and ask for a fix, other comparable libraries/toolset might be posted as answer.

Comment: @rene In which case you might perhaps even be better of on Software Recs if you have a clear, narrow and specific set of requirements, I guess?

Comment: @Bart No, that was not what I intended to express. If you have a strict set of requirements you can indeed go to SR. But if you have a specific issue with a library and in your question you state that you are open for other libraries you will receive two type of answers: answers that solves your problem in your current context or answers that suggest a different library to solve the problem. Indirectly you answered in  that case the question: If I do *foo* is  library *bar* better than *baz*.

Comment: I feel it would also be constructive to ask something like "what are the practical criteria these two things could be compared on". I'm not sure if that opinion is shared widely/at-all ..

Answer (score 20):

No, they cannot be. Comparison questions are *inherently* a poor fit for our Q&A style because there are no bounds to the answers which can be posted to them. Consider the following dilemmas:

- What one person considers to be an advantage in one, another person could consider a *disadvantage*. Not everyone agrees on what features are useful or not useful, and thus **no** feature can really be considered an advantage or disadvantage. It's completely dependent on *your* point of view.
- As two or more technologies become more complex in nature, they continue to approach an infinite scope of features which can be compared between them. Our Q&A is simply not designed to be able to compare *all* of them in an efficient manner, which makes it bear down on "which features are more important?" I refer you again to my first point.

Comment: Comparisons do not have to be about advantages and disadvantages per se. Simply stating differences between two technologies is just as useful and less subjective.

Comment: But that's still an unbounded list that suffers from the reader's point of view of importance.

Comment: ...  and the context in which the reader wants to solve some problem.  Engineering is about tradeoffs; we can hardly build artifacts without choosing between alternatives.  *Thus comparison is fundamental to good design and coding*.   I see arguments against this in SO repeatedly, and I think they are just wrong.    Comparison questions are incredibly useful.  *Answers* that are spam, or unsupported opinion are agreed bad, but that's what answer voting is for.   I'm not going to defend this further here because my (er) opinion seems virulently opposed at SO, but needs stating occasionally.

Comment: Does you position at SO allow you to set the official rules of the scope, or are you answering the question as another SO user?

Answer (score 6):

#### Comparing things fairly is hard, and someone having the necessary subject-matter-expertise to do so is rare (and other problems)

*Obligatory link to https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/big-picture#lang-comparisons, quoting Bjarne Stroustrup's response to being asked to compare C++ with other lanugages in his book ["The Design and Evolution of C++"](http://stroustrup.com/dne.html):

> Several reviewers asked me to compare C++ to other languages. This I have decided against doing. Thereby, I have reaffirmed a long-standing and strongly held view: Language comparisons are rarely meaningful and even less often fair. A good comparison of major programming languages requires more effort than most people are willing to spend, experience in a wide range of application areas, a rigid maintenance of a detached and impartial point of view, and a sense of fairness. I do not have the time, and as the designer of C++, my impartiality would never be fully credible.
>
> I also worry about a phenomenon I have repeatedly observed in honest attempts at language comparisons. The authors try hard to be impartial, but are hopelessly biased by focusing on a single application, a single style of programming, or a single culture among programmers. Worse, when one language is significantly better known than others, a subtle shift in perspective occurs: Flaws in the well-known language are deemed minor and simple workarounds are presented, whereas similar flaws in other languages are deemed fundamental. Often, the workarounds commonly used in the less-well-known languages are simply unknown to the people doing the comparison or deemed unsatisfactory because they would be unworkable in the more familiar language.
>
> Similarly, information about the well-known language tends to be completely up-to-date, whereas for the less-known language, the authors rely on several-year-old information. For languages that are worth comparing, a comparison of language X as defined three years ago vs. language Y as it appears in the latest experimental implementation is neither fair nor informative. Thus, I restrict my comments about languages other than C++ to generalities and to very specific comments.

#### Any such question would need to be focused to a single (or very small set of meaningfully related) objective evaluation criteria

That aside, if the concern is about having an unbounded scope of things to compare between two different things, then that should be addressable by insisting that questions focus on a single, extremely focused criteria that can be objectively evaluated between the two. In relation to this, see /help/dont-ask.

Note: Bjarne's concern about focusing on a single application isn't as much of concern on SO, I think, where more specific focus per-Q&A is generally desirable.

#### `N choose k` (or worse) sounds like a recipe for a information fragmentation, duplication, and maintenance nightmare

My concern is with scaling and fragmentation/duplication of information.

If you have `N` things that can be compared, and you allow up to `k` things to be compared at a time in a question post, this scales as the sum of [`N choose k_i`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) over `k_i in [1,k]`, which is just... really not great. Like- where do you draw the line? If something changes, how many Q&A pairs need to be updated? How many times will the same thing be said between those? It just sounds like a lot of maintenance burden.

#### ... *except* if `k = 1`

What has worked so far and that I think *does* scale and *doesn't* (comparatively) face problems of fragmentation/duplication of information is to draw the line at `k = 1`. That's right- just ask a question about how a single thing fares at doing a single thing. If we can focus on that and do a really good job at it, then at least on paper, a reader should just be able to search for and read `k` Q&A posts.

Doing a single Q&A about evaluating one thing against one criteria is often hard enough (which is why we have the guidelines for constructive subjective Q&A in /help/dont-ask).

#### `k = 1` being the norm, filling in specific gaps with `k > 1` sounds fine to me

If there are specific gaps after good answers have had some time to roll in to those `k = 1` questions that need dedicated attention and explanation to be filled in, then questions can be asked about the specific gaps. The nice thing about that approach (on paper) is that then the specific questions will be *informed* by existing Q&A, and there'll be less basic groundwork info to fill in readers on. The `k = 1` questions would be the pre-readings.

#### On the value and potential problems with `k = N`

I also recognize that having a single Q&A for `k = N`- basically a high-level overview thread could have its usefulness, but there are a couple problems I can see with that (and probably more I haven't thought of):

1. that it could be wading into the ["you could write a whole book about it"](/help/dont-ask) territory
2. deferring to the isocpp link I put at the top of this answer post- particularly the point that the more things you want to compare, the rarer it is that someone actually knows enough to give a fair comparison- though that might be a non-issue if all the `k = 1` Q&A are really really good: Someone could go and read all the `k = 1` Q&A and maybe through that become informed enough to do that, but...
3. `N` tends to grow. What do you do when a new solution rolls in? What if `N` is just stupidly big, or that nobody even knows how big it really is? It's not that it's impossible to keep this constructive, objective, and up to date, but... it does sound like a lot of work. And who would own the answer(s)? The original authors? Then either it's left up to each author to keep their posts up to date and be aware of a potentially very broad landscape of technology... forever? or others edit new info into their post but the original author gets all the rep, or it's community wiki, but then I'd feel a little uncomfortable about who's vouching for the accuracy of the info. Maybe the answer to this is that trying to do this would just not work very well.

Comment: Hum, my 2cts, but as a Developer you/we are first interested in some kind of "Overview", I would think, before eventually drilling down into the `k=1` Thread specific to that Command/Method if we use it/encounter any problem while trying to convert it from Sys1 to Sys2... // Having 10 "independent"/parallel Treads about 10 different Commands is a bit *useless* if there is no *Overview*... This is also how *Documentation* works...

Comment: @chivracq I don't follow. The whole point of SO is to be documentation in the form of a bunch of focused Q&A. And I think you may have misunderstood. Discussion in this meta Q&A is about comparing different things against some number of criteria, such as different solutions' fitness to a task/application- not about just giving an overview about what multiple different things are. See the linked post in the meta question above. It'd probably help if you give a more concrete example of what you're talking about.

Answer (score -3):

While I understand the stance that Stack Overflow is primarily a Q&A site, and the question "What is the best tool/library to achieve X?" or even "What tools/libraries are available to achieve X?" are by their very nature subjective, these are still questions for which I often find myself needing an answer, especially when exploring technologies on the edges of my skill set.

Sure, we can head to Wikipedia and Google in order to resolve these sort of questions, but in the wild we will often find very biased comparisons, and it would be so much better to keep Stack Overflow as the single source of truth for developer technologies.

Has there been any discussion regarding treating these as a different kind of question, with slightly different ground rules / functionality?

1. These questions don't have an accepted answer (new functionality).
2. The answers must be factual and unbiased, and will flagged for deletion if they verge towards emotionally loaded prose (e.g., fanboys or haters).
3. Standard blurb surrounding the question should state that all answers are opinion-based, and the most voted answer is not necessarily the right match for your needs.
4. An additional blurb should also state that care must be taken regarding the age of answers, as tools and libraries evolve fast. It should also encourage contributors to update their answer from time to time, as the tool/library evolves.

I honestly think it is a shame that Stack Overflow steers people away from these types of question, so I hope that there is room to incorporate such questions in a controlled manner in the future.

Comment: You want [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). (The link goes to their question quality guidelines; you have to ask in a very specific way to be on topic there.)

Comment: @BSMP - I hadn't realised there was a separate site for this, and in a way it's sad that there is, as it still feels like we have multiple sites we need to visit as software development practitioners (sure we eventually learn which site is for which, but...). The fact that I haven't come across Software Recommendations through past Google searches is also a concern.

Answer (score -7):

Actually, I think comparison questions are highly valuable, because very often people want a comparison to decide for the right tool. Yes, it is true these questions do not have a definite answer, but they can be a great source of information to make sound decisions. For me it always hurts if good comparison questions get closed, because these question really develop their value over time, and good arguments for and against certain tools raise and help people finding the best tool.

To give an example: [What does AngularJS do better than jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery)

There are more questions like these that have high value, but they just get smashed by the rules.

Comment: Since SO long ago decided that it was not in the business of helping people decide on the right tool *anyway*, I don't think this will cut any ice.

Comment: [What is the benefit of closing useful questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262970/839601)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Can you explain what you mean? When did it decide on that and why? Do you have a link?

Comment: @MaxB: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/