# 'Product Comparison' question on hold, how should OP proceed?

Tags: support, close-reasons

Original question

> #### [Should I use H2 database or MySQL for production use? [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328783/should-i-use-h2-database-or-mysql-for-production-use)
>
> I understand that EMM 1.1 ships with H2 database as default. Is it good for production use?  Should I prefer the use of MySQL instead?

Question closed as primarily opinion based. OP is not pleased at the closing, and is inquiring how to ask. I'm not a pro at this myself, so please provide tips.

The OP is not educated on the pros and cons of each, and would like guidance on how to make an educated decision.

Do you have advice for the OP on how to ask this question, or how to ask a question that would help him on his quest?

I am not trying to bump this particular question or force you to answer an opinion-based question.

I am specifically looking for clarification on how the OP should proceed to get help in this and similar situations. I could say 'not a good fit for StackOverflow', but maybe there is a variation that would be a better fit?

Comment: Paging Yannis: are "what do I need to consider/how do I make this decision?" questions okay for Programmers?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Hmm. Tricky. In this case the question **as written** would get closed just as quickly on Programmers as it did on Stack Overflow. However, a well written "What do I need to consider?" question should be OK.

Comment: @George: [Yannis](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/99456/yannis) is a former mod on Programmers who is usually very helpfully outspoken about what does and doesn't fit there.

Comment: Downvotes on meta commonly show agreement/disagreement with what is being presented. They are likely coming from people who feel this vein of question is not appropriate for StackOverflow and so asking "Why is this on hold" (which is what your title *seems* to ask even if the body doesn't) is something they disagree with. Tagging it with reopen-close (which is seen as a request to reopen the question) probably isn't helping you either...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, Tag was added by another user. I didn't even notice. I updated the question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yannis is an active moderator at Programmers, not a _former_... and I think he once answered similar question at MSE: [How can Stack Overflow help developers evaluate technologies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145813/165773)

Comment: Oops, my mistake, @gnat. For some reason I thought he had retired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I believe the root of the question is that the OP is not educated on the pros and cons of each, and would be satisfied if we could provide guidance on how to make an educated decision.

That may be an important question with useful answers, and I hope that it's kept… far away from us. :)  Questions like that aren't bad in and of themselves, but they're not a particularly good fit for Stack Overflow.  They're too broad (lots of possible answers), and at least partially opinion based, and even though this one is about two particular systems, it's pretty close to a tool request.  Those kinds of questions aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow, where questions should typically have some objective and canonical answers.

The user should take the question elsewhere.  Be sure to point out that it's *not* because the question is bad.  It's not a bad question.  It's *good* to ask professionals and enthusiasts for recommendations and experienced opinions.  But the kind of responses that questions like that elicit aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow.  Comparison questions aren't a good fit either.  See [Can questions that ask for a comparison be constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251328/1281433) for some discussion about them.

When these kind of questions come up in semantic web related topics, I often point people to http://answers.semanticweb.com, which is a Q&A site, but accepts some more discussion and poll type questions.  For Common Lisp, I usually point people to comp.lang.lisp.  I don't know what the counterparts are for this topic, but someone in the field should.  It may well be possible that there's a relevant SO chat room, and if there isn't, that you could create it.  It's fine to try to help this OP, it's just that a Stack Overflow question and answer isn't the best tool to do that.

Comment: The OP is not educated enough to decide on his own and is asking for help. He is asking the wrong way, and doesn't know the right way. My question is what would be a good way for the OP to proceed? Is it better that he leave SO entirely for this type of question, or should he ask a variation such as 'overview of pros and cons', or 'comparison of A and B'?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I updated the answer.  Summary: you can help in chat, or point OP to a related forum, newsgroup, etc.  SO just isn't a great fit for this.  This would be better with threaded discussions, etc., and that's now what the system provides.