# What is the benefit of closing useful questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope, closed-questions

When there are valid questions that "do not fit" within the SO model, what harm does the question do by simply existing? Why chop off the ability for people to answer these questions when experts are ready to? I understand the barrier must be created for low quality questions to generate no more activity, to put a "hold" on the issue and give everyone a clear warning - "do not answer this question, and do not ask similar ones either". But when the question is developer-related, and relevant, and above all, *useful*, what good does closing a question do?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498280/what-are-specific-benefits-of-aws-for-a-saas-product/24498371#24498371) question describes my point precisely, I asked a question about AWS in a developer-context, in about 10 minutes an experienced dev answers my questions with reasonably good answers, the question gets closed, end of discussion. Shouldn't get SO FAQ/TOS be somewhat more reasonable with what is considered a good question and what is considered "off topic" or "opinion-based"? It would definitely help allow useful questions (and answers) to survive, and possible thrive.

For reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957350/is-the-vc-code-dom-accessible-from-vs-addons) was another question that went through the entire cycle of being downvoted, closed, [meta disucssion about the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late), question re-opened, question upvoted.

> *"What harm is this question doing by simply existing? It's on-topic, it's interesting, and someone could conceivably answer it. Heck, someone from MS might see this and answer it, and then it's a great addition to the site. Please stop looking for anything potentially negative about a question before attempting to see anything positive." - [Tim Post♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post)*

Comment: "Useful" is subjective. IMO that question isn't because it's (1) way too broad and (2) way too localized. You're asking about cost, speed, reliability and even things totally unrelated to software development like "am I impressing people by using AWS". It's not a question about a specific, objectively answerable issue but feels like a recommendation question in disguise. I'd have voted to close it as well.

Comment: Where exactly is that quote from Tim Post from so that we can see it within its context?

Comment: @Bruno the quote is on [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957350/is-the-vc-code-dom-accessible-from-vs-addons#comment35682957_22957350).

Comment: The example question that Tim is defending is at least about programming, not choosing a hosting provider.

Comment: @Harsh Gupta  I posted a similar question just now and it did not merely get down voted but deleted.  I suspect this comes up quite often but is considered too outrageous to even consider.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think the overall subject of [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24498280/372643) was off-topic. Rather it's the broad scope of potential answers that causes problems.

I'm certainly [more tolerant than others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262787/372643) in terms of the subject domains acceptable on SO. However, that doesn't mean any question on a suitable topic, even within the context of software development, belongs on SO.

The title of your question ("*What are specific benefits of AWS for a SaaS product?*") looks fine to me (but could be improved because it can be rather broad, the word "benefit" is not great). I don't mind product-specific questions, and asking what makes a specific product different from others in the same field can be relevant and have a clear answer.

The problems arise in the body of the question itself. The bullet points are effectively a number of sub-questions, some of which are very subjective.

> What are the specific benefits of using Amazon Web Services as a
>   server-side backend for a SaaS product line? What are the
>   differentiating features that make it beneficial compared to other
>   hosting services?

As an introduction, that could be OK...

> Cost : Is the price per GB lower than the industry average of $20 per GB making it ideal for large data files?

Surely, if you already know that the cost is lower than the industry average, no point asking whether it's advantageous for large files. If you have to handle large files, from development point of you, you could ask instead whether there are known limitations for large files (e.g. 4GB size limit or that sort of thing).

> Speed : Faster than competitors? Faster upload/download speeds? More parellel threads per file?

Transfer speeds are often subjective depending on where you want to send your data. The number of parallel threads is a more relevant angle. I suppose you *could* have a good an clear answer with a comprehensive benchmark of transfer speeds, but that's unlikely (and if anything, it could be disputed by competitors).

> Reliability : Better reliability due to Amazon network? No data loss? No server instance restarts?

A better aspect of this sub-question would be to ask which exact reliability mechanisms are in place.

> Brand : A service backed by AWS is much more likely to impress big-name clients due to Amazon brand?

That's completely subjective.

> Elastic : Ability to scale billing with usage? Does this actually work or is it a marketing gimmick?

That's asking for a number of distinct user experiences.

> Accessibility : Any advantages with the Amazon network/worldwide coverage over other providers?

Knowing about the network coverage can be directly relevant to the development of your application, fair enough. This can be factual too. Comparing with other providers is difficult in general, though.

> Management : Better management toolset or great access control? Better data/server security?

"Better" is almost always subjective. Asking *what* is provided with the toolset can be answered with facts. Whether it's better than others will depend on what you're trying to do and whether you may or may not need those tools.

> Support : I heard their tech support is the worst in the industry so no questions in this dept.

You're saying "*no questions in this dept.*", but you're effectively asking for comments on the subject. Judging a support service will almost always be subjective unfortunately.

Overall, this question is a mix of "too broad" and "subjective" (and also a mix of sub-questions), even if the subject can be interesting.

The problem with these questions isn't so much that their subject is or isn't off-topic, rather it's the fact that they can't really work in the SO model. The SO model is heavily Q&A centred, with the concept of a single accepted answer. I'm all in favour of having multiple answers that offer different solutions to the question, but it's hard from this particular question to imagine that there could potentially be that one answer that you will choose as a solution to your problem.

I sometimes wish that it was possible to ask questions more open to recommendations or feedback and experiences (still using a Q&A model, with votes), but the fact there must potentially be a single accepted answer means that this would never work. It's certainly a good thing to encourage precise questions anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If we don't close these questions, it basically tells people that these questions are OK, resulting in even more of the same type. That in turn makes it harder for the questions we do want, to receive attention.

Nobody says these questions can't be useful (it even says so in the Close Reason), it's just that they are not part of the (current) goal of Stack Overflow.

Closing them helps us educate users that we do not want such questions, and in an ideal world nobody asks them.

Some quotations from https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

> Stack Exchange is about questions with objective, factual answers. We’ve been crystal clear about this for as long as I can remember, even back to the earliest, pre-beta days of Stack Overflow.
> [...]
> eventually the experts (i.e. people who are teaching you stuff) get drowned out and you are left with an experience that looks more like the magazine rack at a grocery store than a book shelf at Harvard.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing entirely with your point, but people who say "*we do not want such questions*" often think of "*we*" as a wider part of SO than they actually are (including the vocal minority of frequent Meta.SO users).

Comment: @Bruno in general most of the answers on SO are also provided by a minority of SO users.

Comment: @Jack, true, but these two groups are not necessarily the same. There seems to be a category of users whose main contribution seems to be curating, which is good in principle, but seems to go into extremes sometimes these days, and goes in the way of providing valid answers to valid questions.

Comment: @bruno then become vocal if that minority doesn't represent you.

Comment: @Bart, I've started to do that recently indeed, but Meta.SO seems to take a lot of time for what seems little purpose (at least answering on SO, you feel you've helped someone). Meta.SO still is dominated by the ["caretakers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late#comment7112_252077), so it's difficult not to get [downvoted to the point you can't be read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230829/148833) sometimes. Interestingly, some of my answers attract both up and downvotes (one +3-3=0, one +6-15=-9... hard to assess the actual feedback...).

Comment: I can't imagine this is true. When I have a question I ask it, I don't read hundreds of other questions to get a feel for what type of questions are allowed. If the other questions were kept open vs closed I would have never even known anyways

Comment: As somebody who has taught at Harvard and who also has substantial reputation on SO, I deplore the closings of the questions that don't meet the narrow interpretations of the rules. The site has gotten less useful because there are too many interesting and important questions whose answers don't fit in the scope of the rules.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately sometimes questions that some might consider useful must be sacrificed for the greater good of the site. I completely agree that the question is too broad and does not allow for an objective response, which is prohibited. This question arguably becomes more useful when it is closed as it demonstrates to users the way to ask a proper question. It does still exist and is still there for reference anyways. If one question has to be closed to allow for twenty better questions, I think we can all agree that is a worthy sacrifice.

Comment: This is not a sacrifice. When you throw the rotten apples out of the basket you are not sacrificing those apples for the good of the non-rotten ones, you're just doing the right thing.

Comment: Again this goes back to something stack overflow tries to avoid: subjectivity. I tried to avoid this by writing _that some might consider useful_, but once again the idea of a good question is subjective.