# Why is a list of comparisons subjective?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

This question is a response to my question about OpenGL libraries being put on hold.

The question in question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35389455/3359226

The question was put on hold as being opinion based, but I do not understand why a list of comparisons and differences between the libraries is subjective.

Can someone explain why this question was put on hold as opinion based?

Comment: If it's not opinion based then it is certainly "too broad". From http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask - "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.". I can certainly imagine a good answer to that question being book sized.

Comment: In practice, answers to that question will be of the form "I've used X and I like it" or "X is the best for Y; otherwise use Z; no idea about the others".  Those are noisy, subjective and easily outdated answers.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Is that considered to be a fault of the question? The "not a answer" flag exists for this reason, right?

Comment: @Mee: It answers the question, so it isn't NAA. It's the kind of answer such a question attracts, which is the fault of the question, and why "list of things" and "bike-shedding" and such are barred from SO.

Comment: This seems to fail the "_every answer is equally valid_" test for broad opion-based questions.

Comment: Who cares what excuse was used to close it?  It was an attempt to outsource product research to SO.  You are asking SO contributors to prepare a report, presumably with intro, summary, data, conclusions etc, for free.  You shoud not try to imagine the responses I had to reject because of the SO 'be nice' policy.  Summary - bad question, got closed, how sad, too bad.

Comment: see also: [Should framework comparison questions be deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291052/should-framework-comparison-questions-be-deleted)

Answer (score 10):

There are two equally valid reasons for closing your question:

> I do not understand why a list of comparisons and differences between the libraries is subjective.

If I told you that SDL had a terrible API while Allegro had a more reasonable one, that would be a valid answer. But it would not be based on anything remotely like *facts*; it's just my opinion. Both libraries do the same thing, so a comparison of one vs. the other is primarily based on opinion.

Comparisons are almost always subjective.

Oh sure, someone could post a less subjective-seeming answer. But how much objectiveness can you get when you're asked to compare two tools that do basically the same thing? At *best*, you'll get a dry recitation of information that you could find on the website of the tool in question: which platforms are supported, which APIs are wrapped, which framebuffer formats are supported, etc.

We're not here to be your research assistants.

This also brings up an issue with subjective questions: completeness. A *single answer* should be sufficient to provide 100% of the information the question asks for. But comparisons do not easily achieve that, since such comparisons are almost never *comprehensive*. One person will focus on the things that he thinks are important, while another will focus on the others.

The fact that no one answer is likely to *fully* answer the question is evidence that the question is subjective.

> I'm sure there's more.

Well there it is. Not only are you asking for a comparison of specific libraries, but you're effectively asking for a comparison of *every library* which fits some criteria. All of them, whether you mentioned it by name or not.

And do note that this is a criteria that you never stated in anything remotely like a concrete way. The closest thing you said was "libraries that facilitate OpenGL development".

That is an *endless* array of libraries and tools. You could probably find hundreds on GitHub alone.

Even if we focus solely on the libraries you asked about, the list is still gigantic. You're asking users to compare and contrast between over a dozen different libraries. A good answer would have to be massive. For example, [this OpenGL Wiki article](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) contains a list of *just* OpenGL Loading Libraries. It is several pages long, and it doesn't go into any real detail about them or attempt to *compare* them at all. So an answer that just looked at loaders would have to be even longer.

Comment: Yes.  Summary:  "I have to do product research.  It's hard, boring work,. collecting and collating all that info from so many places:(  Ohwait..I can get the SO drones to do all the work for me!"