# Why are two self-answered questions about new Java 14+ features so heavily downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, self-answer

I have just stumbled upon these two questions with a number of upvotes and downvotes as of the time of writing this post:

- [What is the Text Blocks (or Multiline Strings) feature in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65676448/3764965) with 7 upvotes and 17 downvotes. Score -10.
- [How is NullPointerException in Java 14 different from its predecessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65659746/3764965) with 1 upvote and 12 downvotes. Score -11.

I don't understand the reason for the intense chain of downvoting.

Let's say the questions lack quality to be either downvoted or left as is. So we can compare with the recommended reason to downvote (source: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

> - Downvote questions that don't show any research effort or don't contain enough information to be clear and answerable. These questions may also need to be closed.

The question clearly contains enough information to be clear and answerable. Does it show an effort? Well, how much effort the askers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309424/3764965), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/157944/3764965), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40471/3764965) questions took? *None*. Is it okay because these became quickly very popular among users and were asked many years ago? Well, it makes sense until I show you my very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64132803/when-and-how-to-perform-one-to-0-n-mapping-stream-mapmulti-over-flatmap-as-of-j) (having 18 upvotes and 1 downvote) just a few months older than the two questions at the beginning. I think this requirement is either ignored or aimed against the "do my homework pls" question.

The question is understandable, properly formated. Moreover, the self-answered questions are not only allowed but also encouraged and *this* is the case. I am sure they would become searched a lot in the future. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer:

> Yes! Stack Exchange [has always explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

Interestingly:

- The answers are less downvoted (6 upvotes/2 downvotes and 7 upvotes/0 downvotes).
- No negative comments are present. Actually, no comments are present (at the time of writing this post).

**What happens here? What do I miss? Why are these two questions so heavily downvoted?**

(I haven't voted to these questions yet, however, it is my intention to upvote them both including the answers in the soon future).

---

Meta-effect after cca 24 hours (I didn't vote yet):

- Question [What is the Text Blocks (or Multiline Strings) feature in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65676448/3764965) has 42 (+35) upvotes  and 47 (+30) downvotes. Score -5. The answer went to 20 (+14) upvotes and 3 (-1) downvotes.
- [How is NullPointerException in Java 14 different from its predecessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65659746/3764965) with 34 (+33) upvote and 32 (+30) downvotes. Score 2. The answer went to 31 (+24) upvotes and 1 (+1) downvote.
- Fun fact: my mentioned [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64132803/when-and-how-to-perform-one-to-0-n-mapping-stream-mapmulti-over-flatmap-as-of-j) was downvoted (lol, thanks) and the answer remains unchanged.

The two mentioned questions accumulated quite a lot of upvotes and downvotes while the overall score has improved. I see the community here is very split.

---

Meta-long term effect after ca. 3 months (lots of rep and attention)

- Question [What is the Text Blocks (or Multiline Strings) feature in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65676448/3764965) has 52 upvotes  and 55 downvotes. Score -3. The answer went to 42 upvotes and 9 downvotes, score 33. Question is still locked and was deleted and un-deleted multiple times in between.
- [How is NullPointerException in Java 14 different from its predecessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65659746/3764965) with 84 upvote and 52 downvotes. Score 32. The answer went to 71 upvotes and 3 downvotes, score 68. Question was multiple times closed and reopened in between.

Overall still lots of up and downvotes but a bit more up than downvotes lately.

Comment: you can probably add a third one to the list too. This one with 6 upvotes and 6 downvotes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657169/what-are-switch-expressions-and-how-are-they-different-from-switch-statements

Comment: They've all been closed and reopened. I suspect there were probably some comments cleaned up too that would explain matters (and downvoters getting on a bandwagon)

Comment: It looks like these were topic of discussion in socvr chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51347286#51347286

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, I can vouch for there being quite a few comments on the question that you linked, as well as the second linked question in this Meta. I recall leaving a comment on at least one of them. I assume that moderators decided to clean up those comments at some point (or there were sufficient flags raised on the comments to delete them). From my recollection of the comments, they are quite illustrative of the reasons users voted to close and reopen those questions. I think it would be useful to this Meta if a moderator would dig them up, and add them here.

Comment: There's currently lots of irrational voting going on. Currently I'm being serial down-voted, while all answers are technically acceptable and often more accurate than the rest of them. I'd certainly understand why they do it (besides some retaliation for closing their questions), but this statement would get moderated.

Comment: Please repeat it after me - "Answering your own questions isn't bad". Writing a good QnA isn't bad, regardless of why it was written (i.e., to get rep) as long as the post is solid and adds value to the site. Now whether the post actually adds value is up for debate.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, you said "There's currently lots of irrational voting going on." Maybe it's irrational fallout from the recent US pres.vote?  No, it doesn't make sense, that's why it is irrational.

Comment: @Astara There indeed seems to be some sense of discontent, which plays out. I also often notice that actual solutions are being down-voted, while questionable workarounds get upvoted. It's all a matter of popularity (alike in that other one popularity contest which you were referring to), not necessarily about quality.

Comment: I don't have an issue with people writing a Q&A type post, but a common issue is that the question is so terse and contains so little information that any *normal* user coming to answer it would struggle.

Comment: My $0.02: SO questions, regardless of being self-answered, exist to solve problems. The text blocks question is somewhat useful as a tutorial / faq about the feature. The NPE one reads like an announcement blog post split into a Q+A pair saying "look at this improvement to Java" and I don't see how it maps to an actual problem that needs to be solved. There might be valid pieces of info in there, especially the second answer referencing the -D flag (and maybe a reversed question in a few years when no-message NPEs are only found in legacy projects) but for now its value is questionable.

Comment: (Not rhetorical) Is it acceptable for a user to go through a language's release notes, pick the new items they like the look of, and post invented questions for themselves to answer on them?

Comment: The first question is not focussed, it asks four questions which could (and should) have been asked separately, while the second question solicits opinions.

Comment: @l4mpi I think, a new answer to the canonical question [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/2711488) that everyone with a related question gets redirected to, which has been used as a link target more than 10,000 times, would be much more helpful to those debugging a null pointer issue.

Comment: @khelwood: This is likely a valid comment, however, is it really in contradiction with *"If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge"* - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? I think not. Jeff also [said](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.153465208.1116413576.1611563577-1737938750.1588763580): *"Bottom line — never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site. Please do! It’s all part of our shared mission to make the internet better."*.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: *Focused* doesn't mean only one question is allowed as long as they relate to the very same problem. Counterexamples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp). Moreover, the "Needs more focus" closage is described as (emphasizes mine) *"This question currently includes multiple questions in one. **It should focus on one problem only**."*.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Those are examples of questions that aren't focussed either. E.g the first you link asks about JavaBeans and then goes on a tangent to ask about `Serializable`. The second asks somewhat related questions, but are very unspecific (you could probably fill a book answering those three questions), the third asks four questions that are already broad individually, and covers servlets, JSP and JSF (and goes off on a tangent comparing JSF and ASP.net MVC).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Yes, agreed. Notice the downvote ratio is a bit different. Therefore the "needs more focus" is not an issue here. And none of the mentioned (including these in my question) are closed for the very same reason.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I guess the difference is that those questions were asked 10+ years ago, when the community was more accepting of those types of questions.

Comment: I really do not think that the intent of [encouraging self-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is to have people basically recreate change logs. I sincerely hope that questions along the line of the NPE question are not deemed desirable. Yes, there are many bad questions already on SO – which should be a reason to want less of them, not more of them.

Comment: seem pretty conflict about [self-answered-question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.100998985.973500893.1611543169-2019138988.1582683578) which stackoverflow encourage as an option when user creating the question. I don't see any reason to downvote those post

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis The moment when you come up with old questions that are not focused and highly upvoted you are not objective anymore. When we start talking about fairness: The user has earned around 1300 reputation at this point by actually just thinning out and dumping content from some JEPs into Stack Overflow; in a form that is not suited (if we are strict) for Stack Overflow on top. I've seen countless extremly well-written and useful answers on SO that hardly get any attention. Is that fair? No. This is why we should focus on the actual case and stop comparing to other cases.

Comment: @akuzminykh: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512888/how-is-string-concatenation-implemented-in-java-9) is nothing else than discussing a new JEP ([JEP-280](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280) to be exact). It is only 3 years and 3 months old. What's the difference?

Comment: The first one is now sitting at a net of -1, while the second one has a positive score.

Comment: @expressjs123: I plan to edit the question to evalueate the *meta-effect* after 24hrs tonight and just once.

Comment: I looked at the questions and my main problems with them are that they are badly researched (no link to official existing documentation, which is easy to find) and they mostly duplicate existing documentation (haven't compared everything). It's difficult to say if they are really useful. Downvotes can be justified. Closing on the other hand is a different matter. I wouldn't close them.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, it is.

Comment: Perhaps Q/A's of this type should only be acceptable as a Community Wiki. This also should appease those who think this is just a convenient way to grab reputation since a CW doesn't award or reduce rep for votes given.

Comment: And if, hypothetically, every time any new version of anything was released it was followed by 20 questions that were self-answered prompts to justify summarising various elements of the release notes, would we regard that positively or negatively? (I state no position either way.)

Comment: It's too hard to do selfie Q/A here, not worth the hokey workflow, auto-deletion, etc. I'd recommend starting a blog or github.io page instead. Or just write it down and use it, it's nice to be charitable but if people make it hard to help them, it's not the content creator's obligation to fight for the right to literally give it away.

Comment: We need a general discussion about duplicating external content. Bug reports or new features like here or just existing documentation, I can ask for anything. And many people do already. There must be a more general answer to duplicating content possible.

Comment: Who else checked if this question was also asked by Live and Let Live (and also answered by Live and Let Live)..

Comment: To go along with this Question, I wonder why this has been DV'd so much. There's currently 10 DVs, yet this Question exhibits all the qualities of a good question. I guess people disagree with it, which generally is said to not be a good reason to DV a Question.

Comment: @computercarguy *"I guess people disagree with it, which generally is said to not be a good reason to DV a Question."* ... it is generally said to not be a good reason on ___meta___? Do you have examples where it says so?

Comment: @computercarguy This question appears to cherry-pick references, such as similar questions and help pages that agree with the OP's premise. Prematurely disqualifying differing opinions in such a way is hopefully not the mark of a good question.

Comment: @Tom, going down the link rabbit-hole from this Q, it seems as if there's a general dislike of Meta DV's for people disliking the Q's, too. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194361/what-is-an-appropriate-question-for-meta-stack-overflow-if-not-this And then there's this statement that says dislike DVs should only be done on the `feature-request` tag. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193781/scope-of-mso-unique-voting-policy

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, "cherry-picking references" is a key to having a concise Question. If you referenced every single reference, you'd have a massive Q, just like I was forced to do here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222969/how-to-disable-compiler-warnings-in-only-generated-code-without-editing-the-file In a Q like above, referencing "all" sources could be all of SO, which would obscure the Q and be meaningless.

Comment: @computercarguy *Sampling* references is key. Picking *only*  references that agree with your point is at best poor work. The references in the question are very biased, be that intentional or not.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, the Q posts examples of where their claim comes from. It also posts examples that show Q's that have a very different, and in fact completely opposite, results from what should be the same rules. I don't see this as "cherry-picking". If they made the claim "every Q has this problem" and then showed only Qs with that problem, then it'd be cherry-picking. I don't see that here.

Comment: @computercarguy As far as I can tell, there are only references in favor of "no effort questions are okay".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, evidently you and I got completely different things from the Q. I got "why are some Q's without effort OK and these aren't, even though they are self-answered". I would consider a self-answered Q to be the only type that "no effort" would be ok for, since their A would have the effort and duplicating it in the Q would be self-defeating.

Comment: @computercarguy There are dozens, hundreds, maybe thousands of questions downvoted for lack of effort every day. Presenting the two downvoted questions as outliers versus the four upvoted questions seems like a striking misrepresentation of reality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227811/discussion-between-computercarguy-and-mistermiyagi).

Comment: Sometimes the "Change Log" is 1) hard to find on the home page for the program or 2) so verbose it is hard to quickly get the high points or 3) non-existant.  One the "Text Block" question, it was a nice summary of features and examples.  But on the other hand, as akuzminykh pointed out in his answer below, it does ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: When I'm saying arguments lack "lack of research effort", I'm thinking of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-do-i-undo-git-add-before-commit?rq=1 . Face it, basic question with basic explanation attracts a hellish of upvotes.

Comment: @Walfrat: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950319/is-null-check-needed-before-calling-instanceof), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java). Mostly, one-liners. Don't tell me the documentation didn't exist these times. How does it differ from "do it for me"? I see not even attempt to make a research. Why it was ok back then and not now.

Comment: @Walfrat are you aware that those questions are +10 years old? Same with what Nikolas shared. 10 years ago SO was a different site that it's today, it has learned some hard lessons. Namely, that old questions tend to accrue more upvotes just because they are old. [This question is just 8 years old](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/792066) for example and has more upvotes per year than all of those questions.

Comment: Honestly, i do find the one with the NPE not necessary as it does said no more that what i red when java 14 went out. The other one says more... in a way that i don't find that much necessary.  I mean, yeah "%s" for format still work, the string is stored in the string cache. But maybe some people might find it necessary. But it is effectively a very detailed answer. It might just be a better idea to have a proper self answered question than getting quite some poor quality question on the matter. And yes I knew those question were old to begin with.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Personnaly I do consider that the question file oriented are credible if you consider the different possible ways and new possiblities provided by Java 7 then 8 I do think those question bring values, not the two others. Though in a way i'm saying that it's actually the answer that make the question worth, and not the question in itself. If aything old question should have the historical lock so we can't take those as examples for today then.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis " Why it was ok back then and not now." SO's whole voting mechanism was (and is) flawed, people found out later that Reddit style "+1 thanks" voting only gets you so far for making useful reference content, but the popularity voting got SE the clicks up front. By the time it was clear it was making a mess, SE was already a big hit and now it seems like the company is unwilling to make major changes to the UX to allow the site to "grow up" now that all the low hanging fruit is gone. I think Jeff and co. didn't really have a plan for this phase.

Comment: Reference sites have attracted pro devs for a long time. It's easy to get devs interested in a site that preserves knowledge, it's harder to get them interested in helpdesk stuff. It took a while for the (IMO) ruse to fall apart. SE did some good things (like what I put in my "why do you stay" answer), but probably did some not so good things too (possibly lowering traffic to smaller, independent forums, keeping old highly voted wrong information around, etc.)

Comment: For the NullPointerException question, I'm not sure anyone would actually ask that (aside from someone who already knows the answer), at least not in the way it was asked. They may ask what this new option they're seeing means, they may ask why they're seeing a more detailed error message for a NPE, but if neither of those things are true, and they didn't read the change log, then they're unlikely to even *know* there was a change, and they would probably assume it hasn't changed. It seems more like a Public Service Announcement disguised as a question.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis "@Walfrat: This, this, this and this. Mostly, one-liners. Don't tell me the documentation didn't exist these times...." My answer: two wrongs do not make one right. Anyway I inserted a link to existing documentation into the question body of [How do I create a file and write to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java), which kind of answers the question (which has 33 answers!). Let's see what comes out of it.

Comment: Good, nothing came out of it. I answered a trivial question with 2.9 million views and 1.4k upvotes with a simple search and adding a link to the question and the link remains. That's okay. As long as we can improve the questions and add research and that research stays, I'm fine with everything that happens.

Comment: Something I have learned about SO with time(myself being involved in it): Meta, is more like those media platforms, that are used to gain public attention to questions nowadays. To questions, that lack the attempt of research or debugging, getting them into controversies and then gaining reputations indirectly. Without blaming the actual benefitting users from it, the platform leaves yet another reason for not trusting with the *quality* of the content but just the *quantity*. Suggested practice change to the site would be : `Q-Up(+10), Q-Do(-10, -5), A-Up(+10), A-Do(-10,-5)` and good things..

Comment: Aside, being one of the active voters on those threads because of the tags to them. It wasn't about them being self answered that made me close them, it's about the lack of focus/research/debugging on those threads that make them not appropriate for the sites... or else we would soon see the `JEPs` owning one(or even more) threads on StackOverflow. If that's what the platform owners think is right, may God bless its future.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The question [What are switch expressions and how are they different from switch statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65657169/12323248) seems absolutely fine. Some users don't like Stack Overflow to be a replacement for official guides/documentation/FAQs that can be easily found in this case. This question simply explains the feature; it does not describe a programming problem when using this feature. This is the only reason I can imagine why it got downvotes.

The question [How is NullPointerException in Java 14 different from its predecessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65659746/12323248): pretty much the same thing. The question seems fine but has the same "issue".

The question [What is the Text Blocks (or Multiline Strings) feature in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65676448/12323248) is *not* fine IMO. While the previous questions address one specific thing, this question has multiple questions at once that should be questions on their own.

Therefore it should be closed for lacking focus, which it was multiple times. The user often asks other users to reopen their posts. They just post comments under other posts and ask for reopen-votes. This is why this question got reopened again and again.

I've seen this question when there were comments present: Multiple comments explained exactly that the question is not focused enough and does nothing but basically "replace" the corresponding JEP. All comments got removed. In response to that the use editted the "story" into the question that all questions are coming from their team. This surely makes it "seem" more valid but technically hasn't changed anything: the question lacks focus.

It's harsh to downvote the question as it *is* somewhat useful and well-prepared but it's objectively justified.

Questions on Stack Overflow should be specific to one thing. When someone has a problem and searches on the web, then ideally there should be something to be found on Stack Overflow that addresses the exact problem, nothing more. If someone is interested in a FAQ-like resource that provides an overview, then it should be found in official resources or tutorials or whatever. Stack Overflow is *not* the place for it. We should provide answers to specific programming questions, not guides to whole features. This is my opinion.

Finally I'd like to mention that it's a bit difficult to compare voting-behaviour nowadays to 10 years ago. I'd prefer to look on a question isolated to avoid the "fairness-factor".

Comment: How exactly is the NPE question useful given that all it does is explaining "the exception message in an NPE was improved"? The other questions at least give an explanation and examples of a new syntax and can be understood as "how do I use <new feature>" which is an accepted question archetype on SO (focus issues of the multiline q and documentation duping nonwithstanding). But that's not the case for the NPE one and I struggle to see a valid question in there, with the only saving grace being the answer by a different user which gives some useful information about the -D flag.

Comment: @l4mpi Actually you have a point there. Another reason why someone would downvote.

Comment: Regarding the too broad point, it's true that there are 4 questions there; on the other hand, it seems like these 4 can be compressed to one "is there any difference in behavior of text blocks and normal string" (while [list of differences is not okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316864/why-is-a-list-of-comparisons-subjective), in this case the answer is "no", and it could show these as examples)-- would it still be too broad?

Comment: @user202729 I think this question cannot be fixed without adjusting the answer as well. The question asks multiple things and the answer answers multiple things. Again: If someone searches e.g. for: "Are Text Blocks stored in the string pool?", then ideally there should exactly 1 question on Stack Overflow that is exactly that question and there should be exactly 1 answer that answers just that. Focused, precise, on-topic: true Q&A. There should not be an answer that answers 10 things at once, including this. The user can edit the question however they want, the answer has to follow IMO.

Comment: @akuzminykh I don't see anything wrong if the answer demonstrate the point (that text block can be used the same way as normal string literal) by providing some examples? I mean, they're trivial thing that follows from the fact that text block are `String`s.

Comment: @user202729 I don't understand your argument. Could you try to phrase it differently?  Notice that I'm mainly talking about the question, not the answer.

Comment: "*The user often asks other users to reopen their posts. They just post comments under other posts and ask for reopen-votes. This is why this question got reopened again and again.*" If you see this you should flag it for moderators; solicitation of votes is not allowed, especially *direct, targeted* solicitation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not just for problems with code, it's also to ask how code works.

Comment: @user202729 That was an example of "list all differences between 20 different fully featured OpenGL support libraries", which is way different than "what is the difference between two quite similar language features".  Completeness is possible, opinion isn't needed, and formatting it in a non-language-specification way is reasonable.  So none of the "this is bad" apply.

Comment: ......... the point of all these meta discussion is to limit the amount of bad content ("broken window effect") we have to deal with, right? If there's so few of them (languages don't change that often) and half of the community think that it's good content then what's the harm in just keeping them?

Comment: @user202729 1. I don't see anyone here discussing if we should delete these questions. 2. The question here is not if these questions are useful but why they got downvoted.

Comment: It seems doable to edit the NPE question into something more along the lines of "How do I find what cause a NullPointerException in Java" and then the answer (explaining how to turn on the feature and how it works) would be helpful. Not sure if we already have a question like that, though.

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey Nope, will be closed as duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). You know that this will happen.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn so maybe this question should be as well.

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey You are kidding me, right? Helpful Null Pointer Exceptions don't exist, and should therefore not mentioned on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 49):

There are plenty of good reasons why those questions are downvoted, but...

**none of the reasons are because they are self answered**

The downvote button says that "it shows no research effort, it's unclear or not useful" and I agree with all of them.

- It shows no research effort: the features has been just released, and I would be hard pressed to think that the Java team hasn't put a very concise blog post, article or [documentation](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378) about the new features and how they expect to be used.
- It is unclear: when someone asks clarification about a feature, I usually believe that it's the best to include what part of the feature you don't understand, ie. some context about the behavior you expect, or an example of how you think it should be used. Tied with the reason above, it seems that the user just saw the name of the new feature and instead of continue reading, just went to  SO to ask a question about it. We expect askers to at least put some work on their part trying to understand things first, since even [one of the best answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/792066) on the site also have one of the best asked questions on the site (note that the question didn't ask "what is branch prediction", despite the answer arguably explain both, but instead put forward an issue that has a practical application).
- It is not useful: I mean... what usefulness have a question asking "what X is" when X is already described on the documentation?

## The pink elephant in the room

Of course, there must be people that saw these questions and would questioned the asker intentions... and that's ok too. Votes are very personal and you are free to use them as you like, as long as you don't target an specific user. But given that there are plenty of good reasons as to why someone would vote one way or the other, I prefer thinking that the reasons on the tooltip are enough to explain why those question were downvoted.

(BTW, another reason why I believe you shouldn't vote on a post is because you think that the user doesn't deserve the votes, that's voting for the user, not for the quality of the post itself)

Comment: This. "*What is X?*" (to be self-answered with "*A new feature, solving problem Y.*") is not a good Q&A topic. But if it was written in the form of "*How to solve problem Y?*", and answered with "*There's a brand new feature X for this!*", it would be more acceptable.

Comment: I don't get the "pink elephant in the room" pun, specifically the "pink" part. I've generally seen that used in the context of deleted posts, but that doesn't seem to apply here; none of the linked Qs or even the As are deleted. What's the joke I'm missing?

Comment: @cigien https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104243/what-does-the-pink-elephant-in-the-room-mean "*A "pink elephant" is something that people are said to see quite often when they're drunk. It's a drunken hallucination.*"

Comment: @TylerH Oh, I see. I learned something useful today, thanks :) That's a good joke.

Comment: @Bergi In the case of the NPE question, this is not possible. Any question that asks "I have a NPE, and I got that helpful message, how do I fix it" will be closed as duplicate of the [old, "canonical" NPE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). But no answer in there talks about how to actually use the information provided by the helpful NPE feature. And you can't even answer that canonical question, because someone decided that everything has been said about this topic.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn which is why I hate that one. It shouldn't be an all encompassing question, but instead be focused to one topic.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes, "*How is X different?" is not a "*What is X?*" question. For the NPE topic (where the current question is too specific about Java 14, nobody who doesn't already know the answer will find that), I would recommend something like "*How can I find the cause of a NPE?*" (with the answer "*Java 14 helps you*"). Which indeed might be more useful to be merged into one of the wiki answers on that canonical NPE topic, but I'm not a java person. And I'm certain you could ping a moderator to allow adding another answer if it's really considered new.

Comment: You can't answer the canonical question. Because locked.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn You can't answer it, but you can *edit* the community wiki answers

Comment: well, the [top answer to the canonical NPE question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/2513200) does mention the improved error message (near the bottom of the answer). Could be expanded to include the relevant config setting etc as well.

Comment: I wouldn't describe the linked to documentation as "very concise". It has an intro, which doesn't give any sample and I then have to get through "History", "Goals" and "Non-Goals" and "Motivation" before I get to an example.

Comment: @Bergi Sure, let's take the topmost answer and edit that stuff in. Not really a good idea.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I would just delete all of it and write it from scratch.

Answer (score 33):

[What is the Text Blocks (or Multiline Strings) feature in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65676448/3764965)

> *"I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it doesn't present a practical programming problem. Describing a new feature of a language rather belongs in a blog or documentation."* - [3 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676448/what-is-the-text-blocks-or-multiline-strings-feature-in-java#comment116482212_65676448)

No, no, no.

There is no rule stating that Stack Overflow should not be used to document new language features. There is no rule telling that the source of the question must be an acute, pressing, urgent programming problem that must be solved before one can continue; quite the contrary.

And it *definitely* isn't lacking focus or Too Broad. Look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

> **Needs more focus** - if your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format.

This question is not asking "How can I let users log into my web application", evoking a discussion about the various login providers and authentication frameworks out there. It is asking a very few, tightly related question about a new language feature.

The kind of questions that will pull in users to this site for years to come, and lets them stick around because of the helpful information they've found here.

Stop looking at questions through close-vote-colored glasses, i.e. *"I don't like this question and want it gone; which close reason can I stretch to do so?"*.

Comment: "There is no rule stating that ..." Well, should there be one then?

Comment: It's a bit insulting to suggest that people's motivation is that they "don't like this question" and are "stretch"ing a close reason, just because their view of it doesn't match your own. Your opinion that it should be left open is an equal "stretch".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no, why?

Comment: @Clive feeling insulted by someone's opinion is a choice. I am of the opinion that there are some people who are so focused (get it?) on closing questions that they forget what this site is about.

Comment: You're also being quite selective with your copy/pasting of close vote reasons. _This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only._, for a post containing 6 distinct questions, albeit related, is hardly a difficult jump to make

Comment: @Clive that's the difference between the spirit and the letter of the law. A question asking _"How can I create a stored procedure? How should I put it in version control? And how can I let it sometimes return a table, and at other times a scalar value?"_ are wildly varying questions that allow for many different answers. The rule is to prevent _that_ problem. The question we're talking about here, does not cause that problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion, which I disagree with. Good job we've got votes eh

Comment: @CodeCaster For example: Because there seems to be no added benefit in duplicating such existing information. Because it invites templated Q&A. Because it reduces the visibility/impact/... of "real" programming questions. Because it invites questions which lack "any research effort". ...

Comment: _"There is no rule stating..."_ -- except https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Describing a new language feature is none of the things listed there as on-topic.

Comment: @ivan _"how can I use [language feature]"_ _is_ "a specific programming problem".

Comment: The "multiple questions" part of the post is mainly useless filler IMO. It could be shortened to "Do Strings defined from Text Blocks differ in any way from regular Strings" with the answer being "No, it's just another syntax for defining a String" (which should be obvious, because it's still a variable of type String). Yet the poster chose to write a lot of different subquestions with code examples showing that yes, a String behaves like a String, no matter if you read it from a file, define it the old-fashioned way, or use a Text Block. Waste of bytes as far as I'm concerned...

Comment: @l4mpi yet there are about ten thousand questions about, for example, C# verbatim strings, string interpolation, format strings, and so on. It's stuff that actual programmers actually use. There is absolutely no problem in having a canonical question that asks about some of the basics (you know, for search engines), for reasons explained in the penultimate paragraph of this answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster but it's not a "canonical question that explains some of the basics". I could see a useful question in the form of "How do I use Multiline Strings" with the answer being "Here's the syntax, here's a few things of note such as whitespace handling". But the question ATM is "here's a list of things you can do with Strings, can you also do them with Multiline Strings?" with the answer being a very convoluted way of saying "yes, you can, because it's still a String".

Comment: @CodeCaster said differently, if you think the subquestions are useful, wouldn't a copy of the post where all references to Multiline Strings were replaced with a String read from disk be useful as well - e.g. "Can you use String.format with a String read from a file", "Can you concatenate a String read from disk with a constant String"? And if so, what about Strings read from a web page? What about Strings using the `byte[]` constructor? I fail to see how that's useful for anybody because at best it just shows that the asker does not know how classes work in java.

Comment: @l4mpi no, taking the question to the absurd does not help your point. Verbating strings in C# and multiline strings in Java are syntactic constructs that may or may not have pitfalls you know from other languages. The OP is not asking about strings from files or webpages, they're asking about syntax.

Comment: @CodeCaster but that IS the current question after the latest edit. Go read it. It does NOT ask about syntax. The part about concatenating Multiline Strings and String, and using String.format, is directly from the Q+A pair. I'm saying that these questions are absurd and thus not useful. So I guess you agree?

Comment: @l4mpi there is nothing about files or web pages on that question page. Are you looking at the same question as I? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676448/what-is-the-text-blocks-or-multiline-strings-feature-in-java

Comment: @l4mpi and then again, _"But the question ATM is "here's a list of things you can do with Strings, can you also do them with Multiline Strings?" with the answer being a very convoluted way of saying "yes, you can, because it's still a String"_ - **so what**? Finding a question silly has never been an argument for closing it, which has happened three times now at the time of writing.

Comment: @CodeCaster I never said there was. I'm saying the questions being asked are on the same level of usefulness as asking if a String read from a web page or any other source can be concatenated with some other String. Hell, it's a variable of type String, of course it can be used with every function that takes a String arg. There's literally 1000s of Java standard lib functions that expect Strings as arguments but you think it's useful to ask if String.format cares about how the String was defined? If so, why not ask about String.join and hundreds of other functions as well?

Comment: @CodeCaster the pitfalls that are useful to document are the whitespace semantics. Asking about concatenation and methods that take String arguments is just absurd.

Comment: @l4mpi _"I'm saying the questions being asked are on the same level of usefulness as asking if a String read from a web page or any other source can be concatenated with some other String"_ - and that exactly is what I'm calling taking the question to the absurd. Multiline strings (may) have intricacies that do not apply to other types of strings, and this question was asked exactly to address those differences. That you don't understand that is not my problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster all of OPs code examples assign a Multiline String to a variable of type String, and at this point the examples become absurd as they demonstrate in n different ways that a String is indeed a String. Me comparing that with Strings from file/web/etc is another way of saying that it doesn't matter where the String came from. Simply stating that in plain language could be useful, but writing n lengthy examples demonstrating that variables don't care about where they came from is decidedly not useful in my book. You're free to differ but I've not seen any arguments to the contrary.

Comment: You've said in comments that the "multiple questions" part is not a problem / cause for "too broad". I'm saying that part is mainly useless as the listed questions are nonsense. That's primarily an observation and not a reason to close the whole Q (never advocated closing, said multiple times a Q/A pair about the syntax would be useful but the rest e.g. String.format is trash). Btw, the [canonical c# Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3311988) about verbatim strings has good answers, simply stating it's not different at runtime, and not giving useless examples about different lib functions...

Comment: So TL;DR I'm advocating for the question to be heavily rewritten in the style of e.g. the linked C# question, e.g. simply asking "What are Multiline Strings and how can I use them" without listing an arbitrary selection of things you can do with Strings and asking "do these also work with multiline Strings", and paragraphs upon paragraphs of useless examples that say "yes".

Comment: @l4mpi yeah, the question attempts to ask a few naive questions about the new feature, who knows, perhaps to prevent to be down- and closevoted for being too short, and the answer then demonstrates the answer to those questions. I do agree the concatenation and replacement parts are far-fetched, but far from problematic.

Comment: @CodeCaster they are problematic. The questions suggest that there might be a difference to regular Strings, and hide the answer ("no there isn't") behind walls of text. It's simply a bad, convoluted, Q/A pair, and nowhere near fit for a canonical (which it could become by virtue of being first or very early). The fact that a (more verbose) variant of "it's a regular String" is repeated multiple times during the sub-answers is another sign of that. The multiple-questions part feels a bit llike a clickbait headline on a crappy news site.

Comment: Counterpoint regarding "needs focus: the reasoning for picking it in the close vote modal says "*This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.*" The specific question you're discussing is literally (currently, at least) just a bulleted *list of questions*... not even all related to each other. Thus I think close votes of "needs more focus" are perfectly warranted for that reason. (NB - I have no dog in this fight, FWIW)

Comment: @CodeCaster It clearly *does* cause that problem, by virtue of asking multiple independent questions.

Comment: @Tyler I do not see how it allows for _"many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct)"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster You don't see how you could have five different answers, each answering a different question listed in the post, and only that one question? Or how it would be difficult to decide which one to mark as accepted?

Comment: @TylerH: some enterprising rep-seeker could probably take those five good answers, paraphrase them sufficiently, and combine into a single answer :-) I would vote for that, provided it wasn't blatant plagiarism.

Comment: "Stop looking at questions through close-vote-colored glasses" -- ooh yes, absolutely. IMHO that's been a flaw of SO for the last 8-10 years or so. Too many [Soup Nazis](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php)

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes, someone probably could, but someone *wouldn't have to* in order to answer part or even most of the question. That's the problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster "how can I use [language feature]" is "a specific programming problem"" - it's obviously not specific. It can mean "what are good usage patterns of this feature" or "what are the intended use cases for this feature", or maybe just "what are technical limitations for using this feature". There are numerous answers for such a question - all from a completely different angle and all would be on-topic. This is definitely too broad.

Comment: @BartoszKP nice out-of-context quoting there. Ivan claimed _"Describing a new language feature is none of the things listed there as on-topic"_, which I countered with that remark to explain why that is nonsensical. Of course that quote of mine shouldn't be literally used as a question, but that help page also doesn't mention SQL queries, so is SQL off-topic? It was just meant to respond to that, nothing more.

Comment: @CodeCaster What I understood is that you are providing a counter-argument to Ivan's "is none of the things listed there" claiming that it's one of these things, namely "specific programming problem". Which is simply not true, because it's not specific. 

Sorry if I'm not getting something -  however even without any context the sentence from your comment doesn't look right.

Comment: @Bartosz _"How do I use [a language feature] to do [something I want to do]"_ is a specific programming problem. That is my point, and that is an on-topic question.

Comment: @CodeCaster From my experience it's deemed as specific enough only if accompanied by a specific example of [something you want to do]". So while generally you're right, none of these questions provides any snippets to clearly anchor the answers.

Comment: But we already had a question about multiline strings in Java, why couldn't the answer be posted there, instead on creating a self-answered question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string

Answer (score 13):

The immediate reasons for downvotes have already been [explained by Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404693/648265): **many users thought that it's not useful for one reason or another.** I'm going to concentrate on the apparent reason why they thought so.

---

Bottom line:

**These questions are *formulated and focused* in a way that's off topic at SO.**

**They need to be asked (and answered) differently, with a practical programming problem as a base point, to become on-topic.**

- Most probably, that's going to require splitting them into multiple ones to be able to cover all facets of the new features (see below), so it's easier to just have these ones closed and start anew.

---

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic:

> <...> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
> <...>

**Describing a new feature of a language is none of those things:**

---

- [How is NullPointerException in Java 14 different from its predecessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659746/how-is-nullpointerexception-in-java-14-different-from-its-predecessor): *"What makes NullPointerException in Java SE 14 more usable than its predecessor?"*

  - That's a loaded question for starters, and open to opinion-based interpretation, thus **unanswerable.** E.g.: What qualifies as "usable"? How "usable" a random trait or corollary of that new feature has to be to qualify for inclusion?
  - Then, it's not a practical programming problem. It basically says: *"These are the new features. They might come in handy... somewhere... someday... or maybe not."* **Information of this kind is not useful on its own if you have a problem to solve** (see below for more details why).

    - A practical problem (and thus question) connected to this new feature could be e.g.:

      - *Do I need to do anything differently due to this feature to migrate my code to Java 14? E.g.: change some existing code or programming idioms; do debugging differently?*
      - *Do stock tools and facilities (e.g. IDE tools by Oracle and built-in functionality like stacktraces) provide any additional benefits in Java 14+ that were made possible by this new feature?* E.g. richer debugging features/feedback, better stacktraces, improved exception handling semantics...
    - As you can see, with a question formulated like this, **you couldn't describe the feature's traits in an answer.** You would **only briefly list** those that are relevant to the corresponding practical concern (and would very likely link to the official documentation for a full description) -- and **would focus not on describing them but only on how they apply for the practical use case** presented in the question. **You would also refer to any other features that are relevant to this use case if applicable,** not necessarily just this one.

      - **The requirement for the focus to be like this is what distinguishes SO from official documentation and blog posts.**
- [What is the Text Blocks (or Multiline Strings) feature in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676448/what-is-the-text-blocks-or-multiline-strings-feature-in-java):

  - Same as above, not a practical problem. How would any of things listed in the question be useful to know? Even if I know that it *might* help somewhere, that's not useful: even if it does help somewhere, is it really the best/the only solution in all scenarios? Without that additional info, such information is utterly worthless when I have a problem to solve.

    - Likewise, to be on topic, that "question" needs to be turned around and ask about a realistic problem arising from that new feature, not the feature itself. And an answer would contain all practical options, not necessarily just this feature, if some other options are practical as well.
  - As [akuzminych also noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404687/648265), it **contains multiple concerns as formulated** -- which is closeable as "too broad".

Comment: "They need to be asked (and answered) differently, with a practical programming problem as a base point, to become on-topic." -- I'm sorry, this really irritates me. I've asked several questions that are extremely practical but some have been closed due to being very specific to a problem that *I* have faced as a programmer but which may not be relevant to many other programmers in the future. The only rationale for closing (rather than letting such questions die of obscurity) is that StackOverflow is supposed to be more of a curated content. But these questions are "engineered" to be useful..

Comment: ... and now the argument is that they need to be somehow "practical" ??? What gives anyone the right to determine whether they are practical or not? I would argue that "practicalness" merely derives from being able to reuse or get value from such a question -- it's how StackOverflow started back in 2008-2009. People read the questions, feel they've learned something useful, and upvote. Or they are searching for something on the same topic and the question and/or answer provides value to them: upvote. This philosophical debate on "it doesn't belong on StackOverflow" is eltist and unfair.

Comment: Describing a new feature of a language is *on-topic*. Just because there might be a better answer outside of Stack Overflow does not make it off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I feel that "practical" is somewhat misleading and loaded. "Would someone looking for the answer ask *that* question?" seems more like it. For example, someone wondering why NPE suddenly looks differently would likely not search with the name specifically invented for the JEP – if they know the name, they already have all the information needed.

Comment: Folks, stop inventing new, creative close reasons. It’s extremely counter-productive.

Comment: I definitely agree with @JasonS: the "practicality" of question or answer should be counted on votes. I feel that many people are just too trigger-happy with the close voting. I'm afraid that it might be because close voting doesn't hit your repution the same way as down voting. They really just don't *like* the question and they vote closing instead of down voting.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen downvoting on questions is free, too.

Comment: Oh, I remembered it incorrectly that downvoting questions would hurt your reputation, too. Here's the reasoning for "no reputation loss for downvoting questions": https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/ – that said, maybe other people remember this rule incorrectly, too?

Comment: Believe it or not, many people close vote questions because they feel the chosen close vote reason applies.

Answer (score 12):

I was one of the original close voters on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659746/how-is-nullpointerexception-in-java-14-different-from-its-predecessor) and I voted that way due to it being excessively opinion-based as written. Terms like "helpful" and "more usable" are rather subjective, given that the question isn't specific as to what these terms mean in that context.

According to the Help Center's [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) page,

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

As written, this is a "chatty, open-ended question."

On the other hand, the way that it's described in the documentation that the question itself links to is *not* subjective - it's quite specific as to what the benefit of the change is:

> If the option is set, on encountering a null pointer, the JVM analyzes the program to determine which reference was `null` and then provides the details as part of `NullPointerException.getMessage()`. In addition to the exception message, the method, filename, and line number are also returned.

This also seems to significantly diminish the value of the Q&A, given that this information is already clearly spelled out in the linked documentation - it answers the question even before reading the answer.

I can't comment on the reason that people are voting the way that they are on the other ones, since I didn't vote on them.

Comment: It seems as if the initial version of the question does not actually link to the documentation.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added the link to the question as a way to improve it. Surely asking about a subject involves googling it and linking to it, especially if there is official documentation available. I didn't really check how much that would influence any answers.

Comment: The text blocks question is especially chatty.  The answer seems designed to take up a lot of space;  the second half of it is pointlessly specific uses of String, which can all be replaced with “it’s a String and behaves just like any other String.”  All of these questions feel like mkyong regurgitation blogs.

Comment: @Trilarion Just wanted to note the timeline. As this answer says "I was one of the original close voters" and "given that this information is already clearly spelled out in the linked documentation" it might seem as if the target already included the link when it was closed.

Comment: Seeing how even my non-Java search profile immediately turns up the link when dumping the question details in a search engine, I agree though that the question as such answers itself with even the tiniest bit of effort.

Comment: “Terms like "helpful" and "more usable" are rather subjective” — No they are not, that’s ridiculous. Maybe in other contexts they *can* be but in the context we’re discussing here you can’t really argue in good faith that the new feature isn’t helpful or improves usability.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If all new features of a programming language are helpful, we would never need to say it and could remove these parts from any statements because they would go without saying. In this case here I see potential to shorten the questions further.

Comment: @Trilarion Sure, I could *potentially* agree to that but that’s not the claim I’m responding to. On the other hand, while I’m a huge fan of terseness (and so I’d tend to agree) there’s also value in making text read more fluently, and this is occasionally aided by such fillers. How to do this well is both an art and a science, and I wouldn’t want to claim that a particular style is definitely wrong. If you oppose fluff in writing, let’s first ban “So,” as a sentence opener from Stack Overflow. [This Silicon Valley-ism](https://is.gd/lNTmox) is everywhere and it’s incredibly bad style.

Answer (score -45):

If people that wrote the question do not pick an answer, although there are matching answers, I did tend to downvote the question.

Even there is some rule that people can't pick their own answer for a certain time (some days?), I probably don't care and still downvote :D

Guess I'm not the only one ...

of course I'll change from now on, but there are simply a ton of other people using the platform that never go on meta.

Comment: With "picking an answer" you mean "accepting an answer"? If so, what you do is wrong as long as the OP has no obligation to accept an answer. Moreover it can happen that no answer is suitable for the OP although upvoted many times. The non-accepted answer is not a problem. The lack of feedback from the OP to the existing answers is.

Comment: *Please* don't do this. [OP is under no obligation to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It's a 100% voluntary process, based solely on the OP's preferences alone. This is largely why accepts aren't worth more than 2 upvotes, and why the community gets to vote freely regardless of accepts- they simply serve a separate purpose. Vote on questions based on their merit, their clarity, their usefulness; do not vote down questions because OP didn't accept.

Comment: You only cast 22 downvotes so far. So I guess you are only downvoting using this weird and incorrect criteria?

Comment: Just saying, not everyone is on meta reading all these discussions. So why wouldn't other people use the same logic? only tried to give people a different perspective, since the question was why, and there seemed no obvious reason :)

Comment: Well, now that you are on Meta reading this discussion: Please don't do this anymore!