# Why was my question closed with "seeking recommendations" feedback when I asked how to solve a specific problem with a specific library?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Finding all the paths between two vertices with weight limit in a directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201182/finding-all-the-paths-between-two-vertices-with-weight-limit-in-a-directed-graph)

Yesterday I asked the question linked above and today it was closed with a feedback "seeking recommendations". I honestly don't understand in what way my question asked for any recommendations except for how to solve my specific problem (finding the paths with a weight limit in a directed graph with loops) with a specific library ([JGraphT](https://jgrapht.org/)), which is mentioned both, in the tags, and in the body of the question itself.

I don't see what part of the guidelines the question violates. I did provide a working solution using the same library (JGraphT) that I would like to improve upon because that solution is suboptimal.

I would like to understand why the question was closed (and also downvoted before) and how I could improve it so that it's reopened. The only potential improvement I could think of is mentioning the name of the library in the title of the question.

Comment: Potentially they misinterpreted: *"I am wondering if jgrapht provides an API"* as you asking about third party APIs, not sure though /shrug

Comment: There seems to be an occurrence lately: [Why was my question closed for “seeking recommendations” when I had asked for a way to solve a specific problem without using external tools?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405162/why-was-my-question-closed-for-seeking-recommendations-when-i-had-asked-for-a)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I posted a comment under the question itself because it was listed as one of the options in [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I removed my comment there as well. I hope that someone will suggest me how the question can be improved so that I could edit it and put it for re-opening review

Comment: I don't think personally you have much to change. I voted to open it. It could have been an honest mistake or a simple misunderstanding by the closers

Comment: @Nick Asking about a specific third party API is allowed, asking which third party APIs  you should use is not.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I know that?

Comment: @Seth A question tagged with [specific-question] is not really a duplicate of another [specific-question] question, unless the linked Main questions themselves are sufficiently similar. Even though both were closed with "seeking recommendations", they appear to be quite different questions, and the reasons for closing them were likely different as well.

Comment: This is a little bit of a Stack Overflow thing in my experience. Close votes for "seeking recommendations" are very easily hip-fired when there are red herrings in the text. That is not something that will change any time soon because humans will stay humans so the only thing you can really do is read, re-read and re-re-read your question and try to remove suggestive wording from it. "I am wondering" false strictly in that category; you should not have to wonder anything, read the documentation and be sure. So don't say that in a question.

Comment: @Seth, I saw that question before I posted mine and I don't think it answers my question in a way other than what rene said in his answer about everyone being free to use their votes. I wanted to understand how my question could be improved and I guess that's what rene did with his edit. After reading guidelines about re-opening a closed question, it seemed to be the only viable option to ask about it here and attract attention of those who can cast re-open votes.

Comment: @Seth I'm not sure if it's a good idea to send a message with that dupe like Q:"Why was my question closed", A: "It was probably a mistake / reviewers weren't paying attention" unless you want to make a giant "wall of shame" ring of posts

Comment: Related: [How should we handle “weasel words”, or unintentionally broad questions that aren't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402987/how-should-we-handle-weasel-words-or-unintentionally-broad-questions-that-are). Close-voters should read the question more carefully, and not race to the Close link once they read "best" or "API". Also, what @Gimby says.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have made a minor edit in that last sentence of your question to remove the idea that you're asking for a library.

I've also cast the final reopen vote. Your question can now be answered.

Everyone is free to use their votes as they see fit ("accountable" is a word some prefer to mention in this context). Why users downvote questions is only up for speculation, and the same goes for upvotes on PHP answers. Or RegEx.

If you get a good answer, future visitors might value your question more, leading to upvotes. When those upvotes happen is unknown. Allow for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)...

Comment: I upvote helpful PHP and RegEx answers. :D

Comment: I only upvote explained, correct answers to non-closable, [php] and/or [regex] questions ...sooo, not very often.

Comment: "*Everyone is free to use their votes as they see fit.*" This is of course true for up/down votes, but are you also claiming this for close/reopen/delete/undelete votes as well? That's what your answer seems to suggest, to me at least.

Comment: @cigien if anything, I'm certainly not going to close/reopen/delete/undelete as *you* see fit. Feel free to challenge my public votes.

Comment: @rene That's not what I meant at all, perhaps my phrasing was unclear. I meant that your answer seems to conflate the invisible/private votes (up/down) and visible/public votes (close/reopen/etc). One is not really accountable for the former, but as you say in your comment, users *are* accountable for the latter. That's not clear in your answer, especially since you haven't addressed why the linked question got close votes.

Comment: @cigien my first sentence in my answer perfectly takes a guess why the question in question got close votes. Accountability isn't a factor when you vote, only when asked for.

Comment: Yes, your first sentence can be read as a guess as to why the question was closed. I like to state it more explicitly, but that's just a personal preference in writing style. To the second point, it seems we're just using the word "accountability" differently. One only has to *justify* a public vote when asked, but one is accountable for every single public vote that one casts. The justification is expected precisely because one is accountable. It's just a difference in our usage of the word though; I think we're on the same page about this.

Answer (score 11):

I often see one spurious "seeking recommendation" vote on questions in tags I follow ([assembly], [sse], etc.), often on questions that could (and should) have been answered by reading the documentation, typically the manual entry for a specific asm instruction.

Such questions don't explicitly or even implicitly ask for a link to documentation, but I think some people's thought process is something like "this person should have checked the documentation instead of posting this question, and a link to docs could be an answer", therefore "wanting an answer to this is wanting documentation", and "that's the same thing as wanting a *link* do documentation*.  Thus they VTC with the "seeking recommendation" close reason.

(This is incorrect reasoning, multiple of those steps are obviously faulty, and that close reason doesn't apply in such cases.  Those questions are usually just bad and if so should be downvoted, and often can be closed as duplicates, but other close reasons usually don't apply either.)

**Note: I'm not saying *your* question was bad.**  I'm just sharing my experience seeing this close reason pop up when it doesn't apply on questions people happened not to like. Those other questions I'm referring to often are simple failure to check the documentation for the specific instruction that isn't doing what they want / expect.  (In many cases I did agree with the downvote, and sometimes also close for too broad or unclear / needs details, but in other cases there was an interesting corner case that needed careful reading of the documentation and was worth addressing in an answer.)

It's possible someone could have applied the same faulty reasoning here, if they happen to know that jgrapht documentation describes how to do what you want with some function.

It's ok for the / an answer to be "there's a library with a function that does what you're looking for", as long as the question is a specific problem that could also be answered with a self-contained answer.

There's a grey area where what you're looking for is too big to expect someone to write for you as an answer, so only a "here's a library function" answer could really work.  That would be *implicitly* asking for a library.  I don't think that applies here, especially since you're asking how to do it with a specific library already in mind.  That's very different: the ultimate goal of that close reason is to avoid answering being competing recommendations for different libraries, because including a whole library for each minor problem you run into while writing a program doesn't scale well in many languages.

Comment: Do we have a formal `closed:RTFM`? If not, should we create one? Officially designate “RTFM” as a sub-use of some other close reason? Or just allow such questions to remain, open for answering, and let them be voted up or down as the community pleases? (Some of my *favorite* answers on SO merely cite something buried in the documentation…)

Comment: I've seen these spurious/incorrect "seeking recommendations" close votes in the [android] tag and other places as well. Another common incorrect belief is that any question with the phrase "is there any API" is seeking recommendations, even when it's clearly asking for an API within a given SDK (i.e., the question is just "how to do $thing in $SDK").

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude No, "RTFM" is not a valid close reason. This has been [discussed before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253473) and there are a number of insurmountable objections to it. This has even been [proposed network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043), and the conclusion was the same: it's not a good idea.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude No, there is no "this question has been answered on another site" close reason. If it's a popular language/library, odds are the question has been asked before in which case you can close it as a duplicate, but if it isn't a duplicate then as long as it's otherwise answerable it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @RyanM and technically a lot of things are "APIs", the standard library / framework for your language is one, and even CPU instructions are a sort of "interface". A big part of programming is figuring out what API to use for what. E.g., you could copy the GPU's memory to the CPU to do processing on it. That would kill your performance in a tight loop but maybe it would be OK for a screenshot. I think it's OK to assume readers can handle information like that, I'd certainly want it. There's not one and only one answer, but it's not mostly subjective like "what is your favorite editor theme".