# Can I ask a question asking for clarification between the differences of two very closely related technologies?

Tags: discussion

There are libraries, but searching online I can't find anything comparing them. Can I ask this type of questions here or are they too broad?

Comment: It would probably fit better at quora or reddit than here on SO.

Comment: Relevant question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251328/1233251

Comment: It's very hard to think of an example of a question like this that would be a good fit for this site.

Comment: see also: [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) -- _"if you... don't want your question to get instantly closed... - try to keep Gorilla vs. Shark in mind."_

Comment: There are existing examples of this, both closed with a very high number of votes and views: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch and open questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704644/difference-between-solr-and-lucene. Those were just the first two I could think of.

Comment: Note that both of those are *really* old, @Druckles.  I suspect now that the second's been brought to attention, it, too, will be closed.  Standards tend to get tightened up as time goes on.

Comment: I'd have said 2013 is rather old rather than *really* old ;-)