# Does this specific question deserve re-opening?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

Disclaimer: I already know that re-opening a closed question can normally be handled by re-open votes. The problem is that:

- I hold a gold badge for Python so I can reopen the question with my single vote
- a diamond moderator voted for closing. As I respect moderator advices, I will not reopen this question without other advices.

The question is [OOPs concepts possibility in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69794737/3545273).

I admit that the question may not be very well worded, but I always thought that asking for comparisons between languages was allowed here. It is even the only acceptable use case for using C and C++ tags on same question.

If the question was edited with a title like *Comparisons of OOP concepts between Java and Python*, would it deserve to be re-opened?

Or what would it require to become acceptable according to SO standards?

Comment: If you reopen it (based on your gold hammer) it will just be closed as *Needs more focus*...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: I have read the first comment about 1 question per question. But here the 4 points are closely related and IMHO can be handled in a single answer.

Comment: _"If the question was edited with a title like Comparisons of OOP concepts between Java and Python, would it deserve to be re-opened?"_. I'm tempted to close this as a dupe of [Can questions that ask for a comparison be constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251328/can-questions-that-ask-for-a-comparison-be-constructive)

Comment: With my limited knowledge of Java, I don't see how interfaces directly relate to Constructor Chaining and memory management. To be honest, this is a pretty low quality question and I'm not sure why you're dedicating so much energy to it. A moderator was kind enough to close it as a multi-duplicate answering the multiple questions (which is generally not allowed). I would let the question make its way to the jaws of the Roomba and if the OP really cares - they will formulate (a) new, proper question(s)

Comment: @yivi: this one does not ask whether to use one techno of the other... It has visibly been asked by a user coming from Java and learning Python, and who would like comparisons on few points of the concepts of both languages. I admit that 4 questions per question is not acceptable, but I have already seen a number of upvoted questions on concepts or details between C and C++, of course on very specific points.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, as the OP asks ***4*** questions, each of which one could write a good answer for.

Combining all that information into a single answer for the sake of keeping the question open isn't what I'd suggest doing.

As Yivi mentioned in the comments, comparison questions like these are also not the best for for SO.

Comment: Thank you for posting that answer. It got 3 upvotes while my question got 3 downvotes, so the community has made a choice ;-) I love to help beginners to improve their skills but as the community feels that this question cannot be salvaged, I shall not insist.

Comment: @SergeBallesta a worthy goal but there are far better sites for serving that goal. The best you can do on Stack Overflow is help beginners to understand how Stack Overflow is not designed for beginner questions.