# How much deviation from Stack Overflow's guidelines is too much?

Tags: discussion, scope, collectives, discussions-space, nlp-collective

There's [a *Discussion* on the NLP Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76949597/how-do-we-handle-what-tool-x-to-achieve-task-y-nlp-questions) which asks about validity of questions which seek recommendations, are broad, or would generally lead to opinionated answers. I am quoting the *Discussion* here, but use the link above if you want to read its entirety including the comments. <sup>1, 2</sup>

> #### How do we handle "what tool X to achieve task Y?" NLP questions?
>
> There's an increasing no. of questions with "what tool/library X to
> achieve task Y?" questions on Stack Overflow. I personally think
> they're valid but these questions either tend to be ignored or with
> random/opinionated answers.
>
> **How do we handle "what tool X to achieve task Y?" questions in Stack
> Overflow?**
>
> - Close them?
> - Answer them (with much effort)?
> - Ignore them?
>
> BTW, similar flavors of the questions are:
>
> - is tool X right to be used for task Y?
> - I've tried tool X and task Y, why isn't it working?
> - How to make tool X work for task Y?

I am no stranger to different levels of scrutiny within sub-communities. But I am afraid this discussion is advocating for a stretch way beyond acceptable boundaries.

Take these comments for instance; starting bounties on questions that are on their way to be closed. This is a prime example of abuse. I don't believe these bounties were motivated by "malice", rather an experiment, but nonetheless these actions are problematic.

> For an experiment, I'm going to start tagging new tool X for task Y
> NLP questions and kind of log them here for reference and see how much
> data we can gather on this:
>
> *[OP provides a lit of questions]*
>
> I think the above short list would be okay enough to start with latest
> tool X for task Y NLP questions, then I'll randomly pick 3 to put a
> bounty on them to see if anyone wants to try answering them before
> it's officially closed.
>
> - [how to deploy openllm models on virtual machine server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76818899/how-to-deploy-openllm-models-on-virtual-machine-server)
> - [Comparing Similarity Between Two Texts with Doc2Vec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76901179/comparing-similarity-between-two-texts-with-doc2vec)
> - [Library Sentence-Transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76828316/library-sentence-transformers)

---

<sub>1. I was hoping OP would post their discussion on Meta as suggested by multiple comments, but that has not happened.</sub>

<sub>2. Per the title of the question, I am not particularly asking about the scope of "Public Discussions". But I understand that issue can/will be addressed, at least partially, in the answers.</sub>

Comment: Deliberately bounty-ing questions before they're closed is abuse, and should be flagged. What this user is doing is just not how SO works...

Comment: One of the close reasons on SO is "**Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more**
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Comment: NLP itself is off topic on Stack Overflow, if you ask me. There are two SE sites that deal with different aspects of machine learning, people should ask their NLP questions there, unless they are about *programming*.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Fundamentally, what's being asked here and in [that discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76949597/how-do-we-handle-what-tool-x-to-achieve-task-y-nlp-questions) is: "Should questions on Stack Overflow be handled any differently because they include tags which are part of a Collective?"

The answer to that is: "**No**, Stack Overflow's rules for questions and answers are no different for questions and answers which contain tags that are in a Collective than for questions and answers which don't contain any tags that are in a Collective."

Collectives are not a special "get out of the rules" ticket that allows questions and answers on Stack Overflow to ignore *any* of the rules for SO content. If the question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow, then it's not on-topic, regardless of if the question has tags that are in a Collective or not. That will mean that some questions, even many questions, that are within the area focused on by the Collective will not be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This addresses the crux of the issue. But I will wait a couple of days before accepting it, to keep the "door" open. Thank you.

Comment: if some Collective wants to bend the SO rules, they need to get them their own site in SE network. As a close vote reviewer I won't account for particular perversion of a particular Collective. There is plenty room out there for those who are unhappy with specific aspects of SO. I know of a few Stack Exchange sites that accept tool/resource recommendations; heck almost any SO rule I am aware of is bent or even completely disregarded at some of ~200 sites in our network

Comment: Indeed, discussions within collectives are the special "get out of the rules" ticket, not the collective itself ;)

Comment: @ErikA I personally don't care what type of "pseudo-technical" or off-topic questions are asked on Discussions, but what belongs to Meta should be posted on Meta.

Answer (score 11):

I asked Alvan in that Discussion thread why they were doing. They replied:

> The main reason is of the bounties is to understand if anyone would provide a good enough answers to those questions and seeing there's any merit of this small experiment of letting some of these questions gather attention for possible answers

> I didn't reopen any of the questions, I've flagged them for closing but also left a bounty for them. But I guess from the email I've got from SO moderator and discussion here, it's clear that tool x for task y for NLP is off topic on stackovertlow. Will advise others to post those questions elsewhere like corporalist or huggingface forums when appropriate.

So as a PSA (though I think this should be pretty obvious to most people), if you think something should be closed according to guidance in the [Help Center](/help) or consensus from discussion on a site's Meta site, you should not be closing and *additionally* setting a bounty on it. Closure *prevents* answers from being posted for a reason: either the question needs improvement (Ex. to be answerable at all, or to be focused enough for Stack Overflow's standards of constructive Q&A), or it is off-topic.

As for the specifics of this scenario- asking about fitness of tools to a task, for questions that are open-ended about what tools to used, see also [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479/11107541). Personally, I think (though I could be wrong) a question asking for what tool is suitable for a job can be made constructive if the set of tools is a closed set (not a free for all of suggestions), and is reasonably small, and the question clearly lays out a set of goals or desirable properties that can be evaluated against objectively, and explicitly insists on getting measured rationales from answers (basically, the question follows the guidelines for "good subjective" in /help/dont-ask).

Comment: In the event users don’t understand, offering a bounty prevents questions that would be closed from being closed, until the bounty expires or a moderator injects themselves in the process and reverts the bounty. A bounty offered on a question that should be closed is one of the most toxic things that users can do only short of deleting a question after an answer had been submitted but not upvoted.

Comment: Your criteria for when a "tool for the job" question would be OK are reasonable ... but (IMCO) they are unlikely to be met.

Comment: @StephenC unlikely to be met *with the current guidance users are generally provided when asking questions currently. The ask question wizard is specifically tailored toward pushing users to ask debugging questions and is a rather poor fit for good-subjective questions.