Make it clearer that Discussions is not for meta about Discussions
Recently someone got upset about having a Discussions post deleted, and made another Discussions post to complain about it.
Notwithstanding any possible merits of the complaint, it certainly belongs here on Meta, if anywhere.
Currently, the apparent policy labels "Discussions about the Stack Overflow experience broadly" as merely "discouraged", which severely undercuts the community's ability to self-govern. The usual crowd of Meta watchers and site curators can't really be expected to trawl through Discussions to look for posts like this.
Worse yet, those guidelines are highly undiscoverable. They're behind a "See full Discussions guidelines." link, under a details fold, in the sidebar "Discussions guidelines". This link also has no underline and almost no visual contrast in dark mode:

Please fix things so that it's immediately clear to new users that if they have a problem with the governance of Discussions that they should take it to Meta, where community members who actually care are actually likely to be present.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426196/how-much-deviation-from-stack-overflows-guidelines-is-too-much

I went ahead and deleted the discussion referenced here. Thanks to those who responded with helpful replies.

@GeorgeStocker We can't use Discussions (Labs) for (meta) discussing Discussions (Labs). For that use https://meta.stackoverflow.com with the [meta-tag:discussion] and [meta-tag:discussion-space] tags :D or [chat], X (formerly Twitter), Reddit, Discord, or whatever platform you like.

I am more surprised that the user knew about discussions but not about meta. Isn't there some participation barrier for discussions? How do new users find their way there without learning more about the site?

re "Discussions is not for meta about Discussions" - to a certain extent, this is not true right now (unfortunately). see my quote of berthold's reason for removing downvotes and my response to it in the second half of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429384/11107541. re "those guidelines are highly undiscoverable" - this is (also unfortunately) for the most part the status quo of in-UI guidance on SO.

@Dharman Discussions is the shiny new beta feature specifically intended to get people to interact and talk more. Why would you expect it to be hidden away or gatekept?

Yeah that's the consequence... discussions are essentially a dumping site. People will post whatever they cannot on the main Q&A site. Probably either blissfully unaware that meta exists, or painfully aware that meta likes its downvotes.
